# NPM error! git dep preparation failed, while installing a git repo

Tags: node.js, npm, devops, npm-install

I was installing a git repo with `npm install` and it took so much time like 30 minutes and then throw these errors, screen shot attached of errors.

I tried cleaning cache and deleting node modules, packagelock.json as it was recommended by others who face the similar type of problem, but it does not work for me.

the repo i am fork and installing: https://github.com/saadpasta/developerFolio

please help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Would highly suggest not posting screenshots and rather paste code.
Now regarding the issues try the following

Step 1:

```
$ npm cache clean --force
```

Step 2:

Delete node_modules by $ rm -rf node_modules also delete package-lock.json

Step 3:

Update the npm to the latest stable version

```
npm install -g npm@7.6.0
```

Step 3:

```
npm install
```

To run npm again,

```
$ npm start
```

hope this works for you